# how to make icons in google custom menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

In google apps (docs, sheets, etc)

Is it possible to make icons in custom menus similar to ones in the insert menu? If so how would I go about it? html service?

The ones next to chart, link, image or even next to bold, italic, etc

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451501/can-you-make-menu-items-in-google-spreadsheet-custom-menus-tickable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no exposed method to put graphic icons in the menu. The best you can do is use Unicode characters such as `✘` and `☢`