# Using Unicode in google-apps menu item

Tags: javascript, unicode, google-apps-script

I would like to use a unicode symbol for Power, &#x23FB, in my drop-down menu.  Here is a link saying it can be done; however, I can't figure how to code it.

[how to make icons in google custom menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032379/how-to-make-icons-in-google-custom-menu/42032473#42032473)

```
var menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
    menu.addItem('&#9824', 'Run App');
    menu.addToUi();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the code. Cut and paste the character. Like '☢' The Apps Script IDE and all the apps support unicode.

```
var menu = DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
    menu.addItem('☢', 'Run App');
    menu.addToUi();
```